# HTTPS URL Api rejected by google play store

Tags: android, https

I have updated my application in play store. suddenly it has been rejected. 
It's saying that 
Security alert
Your app is using an unsafe implementation of HostnameVerifier. Please see this Google Help Center article for details, including the deadline for fixing the vulnerability.

Vulnerable classes:

```
com.xxx.xxx.network.NukeSSLCerts$2
```

My NukeSSLCerts.java class below
I used the same code last September, It has updated. but today rejected.

```
public class NukeSSLCerts {
public static void nuke() {
    try {
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        X509Certificate[] myTrustedAnchors = new X509Certificate[0];
                        return myTrustedAnchors;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                        try {
                            certs[0].checkValidity();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            throw new CertificateException("Certificate not valid or trusted.");
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                        try {
                            certs[0].checkValidity();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            throw new CertificateException("Certificate not valid or trusted.");
                        }
                    }
                }
        };

        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

}

My android dependencies like this

```
dependencies {
final SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION = '25.0.1'
final FIREBASE_VERSION = '10.0.1'
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
compile "com.android.support:design:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"

compile files('libs/volley.jar')
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$FIREBASE_VERSION"
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

}

Any suggestion to overcome from this App update reject issue. 
I didn't use any webview too.

Comment: Get rid of the `HostnameVerifier` from your code.

Comment: You mean need to remove this line 
 HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                return true;
            }
        });

Comment: Correct. That line is what the Play Store is complaining about.

Comment: Okay I will try.. 
Thanks

Comment: They rejected again after I remove this... 

We rejected app for violating our Malicious Behavior or User Data policy. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still available on Google Play.

This app uses software that contains security vulnerabilities for users or allows the collection of user data without proper disclosure.

Below is the list of issues and the corresponding APK versions that were detected in your recent submission. Please upgrade your app(s) as soon as possible and increment the version number of the upgraded APK.

Comment: I do not know what to tell you. As far as I am concerned, your `NukeSSLCerts` does not belong in a production app. But, the email that you received should have more details ("Below is the list of issues").